Does "to live well" imply to live in the lap of luxury?
I happened to see this phrase in Collins dictionary
There are 2 entries

live well
in American English

to live in luxury
to lead a virtuous life

live well  (AmEng)
to live comfortably
They're not wealthy but they live well

Say the living cost in Vietnam is much lower than in the USA.
An American man moved to Da Nang - a city near a beach in Vietnam. With just 1000 USD - 1500 USD a month, he can rent a house, eat seafood every day (since he lives near the beach so seafood is cheap there). Generally, if he doesn't go to expensive places like a resort, he can have a comfortable life there.
The above link says "to live well" is to live in luxury.
Is that phrase just used for people who can buy luxurious stuff or who can have a comfortable life with all basic things he needs as long as he doesn't spend on luxurious things?
Can I say "He lives well with just under 1500 dollars a month there"?

You have the meanings, you decide.

The range of meanings Collins gives should tell you that it impossible to know without further context what the speaker means when saying  "He lives well".

I'd go crazy or get sick if I had to eat sea food every day, or even every week.

@MichaelHarvey Some people say that about British cooking.

@TimR - the best British cooking is world class; we've come a long way since that trope was valid around 1950 or so.

The best seafood isn't "fish and chips". I'd happily eat the best British seafood every day. Unfortunately most of my countrymen turn their collective noses up at the good stuff, so I all gets shipped off to China.

There's a local "crab shack" that won best-in-county. Since the ocean is 90 minutes away and the northern tip of Chesapeake Bay is 40 miles away, I asked where they sourced their crab. "We get it canned, from Viet Nam."

Michael and Tim - Bickering about national cuisines is not relevant or helpful.

Takeaway: A word (or phrase) can be used for different meanings; it doesn't necessarily mean all of them at once. Just because a bird "flies high" and a rocket "flies high" doesn't mean the bird flies as high as the rocket, just that this phrase was useful in both cases.

No, there are many ways to live "well" and it is a matter of opinion what is better way to live.

Joe lived well.  He led a simple life, in a small log cabin, surrounded by nature, his friends and his dogs.

I disagree with the simple dictionary definition of "luxury".

"They certainly lived well; a huge house and a three-car garage and garden".

Yes,  what is "well" is a matter of opinion.  That speaker has certain opinion ...

The definition cited by the OP is American English... so maybe that makes a difference. Would I say Joe "lived well"?  I might've said "Joe was content [with his life]…". Anyway Cambridge has this example of usage On his income, they can afford to live well.

@Mari-LouA No, it doesn't make a difference. In American English to "live well" has a wide range of meanings and there's no way to know what it means in isolation.  Live in extravagant luxury, live in relative comfort but not extravagantly, live wholesomely, live justly.
